# How to count the number of IDs where another column equals a specific value using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi could anyone help me out?
I'm trying to group the IDs and have a counter for the number of "t" found in a column for each ID.

```
f1 = df3[df3['listing_id'].value_counts().reset_index().str.contains('t')]
count = f1['available'].value_counts().reset_index()
print(count)
print(f1)
```

[image: Data file]

An example output would be:

```
   ID   Number of t
14250             1 
12351            10
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I worded this incorrectly. Not sure how to word it.

Comment: include an  example dataframe in your question so that people don't have to make it themselves, makes it more likely that someone will answer your question.

Comment: try `df.groupby('listing_id')['available'].count()`

Comment: Will do thanks for the feedback. Did my wording make sense?